# String getline(cin,variable) function is skipping some lines of code

Tags: c++

My program skips some code when I use the getline(cin,variablehere) function. I don't know whats wrong with the code. See the output below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string getfirstname;
    string lastname;
    string address;
    int contactnumber;
    cout << "Enter First name : ";
    getline(cin, getfirstname);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter Last name : ";
    getline(cin, lastname);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter Address : ";
    getline(cin, address);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter Contact number : ";
    cin >> contactnumber;
    cin.ignore();

    CurrentNumberOfContacts += 1;
    cout << "Successfully added to contact list!" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to add another contact ? [Y/N] ";
    cin >> response;

    //more lines of codes below
    return 0;
}
```

I have inputed 'int' as data type because it will contain numbers only

[image]

Comment: Remove the screenshot and post the output here

Comment: A telephone number isn't an integer.

Comment: you're using cin >> contact number instead of getline(cin, contactnumber)

Comment: That would be even less correct as written.

Comment: I'm sure there is a reason for `cin.ignore()` after **each** of those `getline` calls. I just can't think of what it could be. Perhaps an alternate idea would be to actually *check* the success/failure results of your IO operations rather than assume they succeeded.

Comment: `std::getline()` removes the residual newline character. There's no need for an intersecting `ignore()` call.

Comment: This code does not produce that output.

Comment: The contact number wouldn't happen to be a single digit number would it?

Comment: I think if you remove all the `ignore()` calls after the `getline()` calls that should improve things.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it doesn't even compile in fact. CurrentNumberOfContacts is not declared.

Comment: This program does not correspond to the screenshot. Besides the fact that it doesn't compile; if you enter your first name and press Enter, then the program blocks for input again because of the `cin.ignore()`.  Please make sure that your screenshot is produced by compiling and running the exact code you have posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend removing **all** the `cin.ignore()` commands.

One of the problems with user input is that the `>>` operator does not take the RETURN character out of the stream so if you follow it with a `getline()` the `getline()` will read the RETURN character instead of what you want to type in.

So I would change *all* your `getline()` to this:

```
// cin >> ws will skip any RETURN characters
// that may be left in the stream
getline(cin >> ws, lastname);
```

Also remove **all** of your `cin.ignore()` commands. They are not doing anything useful when used after a `getline()` command and if you change your `getline()` commands as I showed they should not be necessary at all.

**So this should work:**

```
int main()
{
    string getfirstname;
    string lastname;
    string address;
    char response;
    int contactnumber;
    int CurrentNumberOfContacts = 0;

    cout << "Enter First name : ";
    getline(cin >> ws, getfirstname);

    cout << "Enter Last name : ";
    getline(cin >> ws, lastname);

    cout << "Enter Address : ";
    getline(cin >> ws, address);

    cout << "Enter Contact number : ";
    cin >> contactnumber;

    CurrentNumberOfContacts += 1;
    cout << "Successfully added to contact list!" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to add another contact ? [Y/N] ";
    cin >> response;

    //more lines of codes below
    return 0;
}
```

Strictly speaking not all of your `getline()` functions need to employ the `cin >> ws` trick. I suppose the (incomplete) rules are as follows:

If you use a `std::getline()` after a `>>` then use:

```
std::getline(cin >> ws, line);
```

Otherwise just use:

```
std::getline(cin, line);
```

Comment: It would be more concise to just use `cin >> lastname`, which will automatically ignore whitespace and function the same for the typical input case (one word per line).

Comment: @Wug some names have spaces (eg Mc Manners or Du Val)

Comment: @Galik Oh yeah. I get that mixed up with `scanf("%c"`.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >>` and `getline` do not cooperate very well. They have different strategies for how to deal with whitespace. `getline` removes the newline character, but `cin >>` leaves it. This means that after you use `cin >>` to read something, there will be a newline character left waiting in the input stream for the next `getline` to "use". Which means it will read an empty line into the string.

Comment: That's only if he's using `std::getline()` directly *after* the use of formatted input. In this case it has nothing to do with formatted/unformatted input.

Comment: Eventually he's going to be calling this in a loop, otherwise he wouldn't be bothering to use that `CurrentNumberOfContacts` variable he forgot to include the declaration for.

Comment: @Wug certainly may-well go into a loop... someday, which means this answer, inaccurate as it is regarding how `std::cin` is somehow divergent than other text-mode streams when using `std::getline` (it isn't), would *possibly* make a decent starting point for an answer to the *next* question; not this one.

Comment: I don't think that he was implying `cin` somehow behaves differently, but rather that mixing formatted and unformatted input is clunky in general.

Answer (score 1):

2 things. First, you don't really need cin.ignore() in this case as your using

```
getline().
```

before

```
cin >> variable
```

Second, I don't know why your program doesn't run, but I would suggest using a

```
getline()
```

call and see if that works. But I see no reason why your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Galic is quite good but If you want to read a line of characters without discarding the leading spaces you need another solution.

You could do:

```
char a='\n';
while (a=='\n')
{
    cin.get(a);
}
cin.unget();
```

before doing your first getline. This assumes no trailing space resulting from a previous cin and that your first input line is not empty.